# SQL - Get the value from the next lowest ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm working in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Not really sure how to explain this but it's best if I just explain with an example.

So I've figured out how to get the next lowest ID, that is fairly simple. But once i get that row i need to take the value from it and apply it to the next highest value.

If I have 4 rows

```
ID      value
-------------
10        50
30       200
20        75
25       100
```

I want to take the value each row and applying to the row with the next highest ID. So it should look like this.

```
ID      value
-------------
10      null or 0
30      100
20       50
25       75
```

Since there is no row before 10 ID, that row should have a value of null or 0, doesn't matter. And the others should just follow the pattern of taking the value from the row with the next lowest ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [**`LAG()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql):

```
Select  Id, Lag(Value) Over (Order By Id) As Value
From    YourTable;
```

Working demo:

```
Declare @YourTable Table
(
    Id      Int,
    Value   Int
);

Insert @YourTable
Values (10, 50), (30, 200), (20, 75), (25, 100);

Select Id, Lag(Value) Over (Order By Id) As Value
From   @YourTable;
```

> Results

```
Id  Value
10  NULL
20  50
25  75
30  100
```

Comment: WOW this is really neat, never knew about this since it doesn't show up as a key word (blue color font) in SSMS.

I think i can solve my problem with this.